# can you use length for a boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I'm trying to get an input(year) from the user and if the user enters four digit input(which is the length) then it will print the year, but if the user enters any other length it will ask again. Why I can't do(year.length ==4); doesn't it means that if the year length is 4 then finish the loop? Thanks

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class years {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
      year = input.nextInt();
    }while(year.length == 4);

    System.out.println("Year is " + year);
  }
}
```

Comment: int is a primitive, and you can't call a method or get a property from a primitive. So `year.length` makes no sense at all.

Comment: `year` is a primitive `int`, which has no fields. If you to know if it's 4 digits in length, just check if `year >= 1000 && year <= 9999`. Also, your loop will continue as long as the condition is true, which seems to be the opposite of what you want.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It makes some sense, it's just incorrect. :)

Comment: @shmosel: not to the Java compiler. ;)

Comment: @shmosel Thanks, now that makes sense, I don't know what I was trying to do. Can you please explain me What does you mean by "year is a primitive int, which has no fields. " Thanks again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430582/primitive-data-types-in-java

Comment: @shmosel thank you so much

Comment: @shmosel So, there is no way we can use that .length method with a primitive type? Right? But we sometimes use that, don't we? Thanks

Comment: You're probably confusing ints with strings. You can do `String.valueOf(year).length` if you want.

Comment: @shmosel  Ah now it makes sense, yeah I was wrong, we can't check the length of an integer because it's just a single value. Right?