# Scala calling Java method with array parameter

Tags: java, scala

Supposed I have a Java API like below:

```
public class JavaApi<T> {
    public void foo(T[] data) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I'd like to call it from Scala with the following class:

```
class Caller[T] {
    val javaApi = new JavaApi[T]()

    def callApi(data: Array[T]) = javaApi.foo(data)
}
```

On compile, I get the following:

```
type mismatch;
found   : Array[T]
required: Array[T with Object]
Note: T >: T with Object, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may with to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: T with Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
  def callApi(data: Array[T]) = javaApi.foo(data)
```

Comment: Because your Scala code places no type constraint on `T`, the latter could be an `AnyVal`, which is incompatible with your Java code. Therefore, you should define your `Caller` class as `class Caller[T <: AnyRef] {...}`.

Comment: Thank, that clears up the compilation issue. But I thought when compiled, all classes are rooted to Object regardless whether it's scala or java class?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that...

Comment: What I'm saying is that I thought all classes eventually extending `java.lang.Object` regardless whether the class is written in Scala or Java. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You may review the [Scala type hierarchy](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types). More specifically the phrase:

> If Scala is used in the context of a Java runtime environment, then
>   scala.AnyRef corresponds to java.lang.Object

So, by changing it as Jubobs suggested you are sure that the type correspond to an object:

```
class Caller[T<: AnyRef] {
    val javaApi = new JavaApi[T]()

    def callApi(data: Array[T]) = javaApi.foo(data)
}
```

So if you need any value type like int, char, boolean you will need to convert them to their object equivalent boxed Java type like Integer, Character or Boolean. See:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by **Java** does not support polymorphic of [primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430582/primitive-data-types-in-java).

Although **Scala** deal anything as **Object** but after **compiler** compile, maybe it will convert **object** to **primitive type arrays** for performance, such as:

```
scala> var a = Array(1, 2, 3)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
scala> :javap -c a
public class $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$ {
  ...
  public int[] a();
  ...
```

As you can see, the above `Array[Int]` has been convert to `int[]` **primitive type arrays**.

so for this reason, this maybe cause incompatible for **Java** method.

Solution:

1. As @Jubobs said, bound `T` to `T <: AnyRef`. as `val a = Array[Integer](1, 2, 3)`, the compiler will deal it as `Integer[]` type.
2. Use `List` to replace `Array`,`List` always `reference` type.

Reference:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-750