# How is int implemented in Java?

Tags: java, int

According to the docs on `Integer` class:

> The Integer class wraps a value of the primitive type int in an object. An object of type Integer contains a single field whose type is int.

and the docs on `int` :

> By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of `-2^31` and a maximum value of `2^31-1`.

also, according to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10430634/4738175):

> In Java, every variable has a type declared in the source code. There are two kinds of types: reference types and primitive types. Reference types are references to objects. Primitive types directly contain values.

So, my **question** is : How is the `int` primitive type implemented in Java? `Integer` being a class can imagine creating its object. However again `Integer` class uses `int`. In what way is `int` implemented to java so that we are allowed to use it and allowed to perform all its arithmetic operations. An insight onto this would be much helpful.

I tried many existing answers and articles, however did not find an answer to my question, that include:

- [Primitive Data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
- [Class Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)
- [Java: Primitive Data types](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/java-data.html)
- [Can an int be null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254435/can-an-int-be-null-in-java)
- [Primitive data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type)

**PS:**

*If any part of my question is unclear/incorrect, kindly let me know in the comments section.*

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. What do you mean by "implemented"?

Comment: It's implemented as 32 contiguous bits in memory. What kind of an answer are you looking for?

Comment: @shmosel ie when we are using  `Integer` , it's an object of `Integer` class. same way, what are we accessing when we use `int` ? And how is it defined in the java language?

Comment: @TedHopp is `int` defined as part of any class ?

Comment: @OBX its not defined as a part of any class instead its definition is in java compiler.

Comment: No. Java primitives are completely separate from classes.

Comment: @TedHopp That's what I was asking for. An answer on how and where these are implemented. with links for further reading if available !

Comment: `int` and other primitive types are implemented as values on the stack. There are byte code instructions for int load, store, add, ... `Integer` is an ordinary class. Every instance is stored as a reference to a heap node, and that node contains an `int` variable. Is this what you're asking? See the JVM Spec.

Comment: @Jerry101 - Not just the stack. Java `int` values can also live on the heap (for example, an `int` field in a class, or an element of an `int[]` array).

Comment: @TedHopp: I think Jerry101 is aware of this. Notice the: *Every instance is stored as a reference to a heap node, and that node contains an int variable-* . But yes, your `int[]` is another example for this

Comment: @OBX Assuming that we answered your question. What would you do with that answer. Or, in other words: why do you need to know this in the first place? You should answer this in your question, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int` and other primitive types are implemented directly by the Java compiler and the [JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.2). They are not classes. They are value types, not reference types.

The compiler emits byte codes like iload, iadd, and istore, with no method dispatch involved.

`Integer` is pretty much an ordinary class. Its instances are allocated on the heap. Each instance contains an `int` value.

Comment: I think this is most specific a non-jvm developer can provide. For more details I suggest to dig into an jvm implementation, e.g. open jdk, http://openjdk.java.net/