# Python deploy to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying python project deploy to GAE. But I am giving this error message "Line 14, column 1: Expected scalar for String type but found: sequence start"

can you help me please

app.yaml

```
application: app_name    #.appspot.com
version: baseline

runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes 

default_expiration: 1h

builtins:
# Deferred is built in to Ferris. Do not enable it, it may lead to import errors.
- appstats: on  # Also turn on appstats in settings.py

includes:
- ferris/include.yaml
# If plugins require inculdes, put them here.

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: lxml
  version: latest
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: webob
  version: latest

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?app\.ya?ml
- ^(.*/)?index\.ya?ml
- ^(.*/)?#.*#
- ^(.*/)?.*~
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
- ^(.*/)?\..*
- ^(.*/)?.*\.scss
- ^(.*/)?.*\.less
- ^/docs*

handlers:
# Main script
- url: .*
  script: main.main_app
  login: required
```

include.yaml file content is here

```
handlers:
# Static resources
- url: /static
  static_dir: app/static

- url: /css
  static_dir: app/static/css

- url: /js
  static_dir: app/static/js

- url: /img
  static_dir: app/static/img

# Ferris static resources
- url: /ferris/static
  static_dir: ferris/static
  expiration: 7d

- url: /ferris/css
  static_dir: ferris/static/css
  expiration: 7d

- url: /ferris/js
  static_dir: ferris/static/js
  expiration: 7d

- url: /ferris/img
  static_dir: ferris/static/img
  expiration: 7d

- url: /ferris/fonts
  static_dir: ferris/static/fonts
  expiration: 7d

# Top-level static files
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: app/static/favicon.ico
  upload: app/static/favicon\.ico
  expiration: 7d

- url: /robots\.txt
  static_files: app/static/robots.txt
  upload: app/static/robots\.txt
  expiration: 7d

- url: /humans\.txt
  static_files: app/static/humans.txt
  upload: app/static/humans\.txt
  expiration: 7d

# Maps plugins/{plugin}/static to /plugins/{plugin} 
- url: /plugins/(.*?)/(.*)
  static_files: plugins/\1/static/\2
  upload: plugins/(.*?)/static/(.*)

# Cron prefix is admin-only.
- url: /cron/.*
  script: main.main_app
  login: admin

# Used to fix imports before running deffered tasks.
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: main.deferred_app
  login: admin
```

Comment: Can you please include the contents of app.yaml? Like the actual text of the section that is shown in the picture

Comment: How are you deploying?

Comment: codenvy.com online ide

Comment: Can you also include ferris/include.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspecting the error

> Expected scalar for String type but found: sequence start"

*What is a scalar type?*
[A scalar is a "single" value - integer, boolean, perhaps a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623130/scalar-vs-primitive-data-type-are-they-the-same-thing)

---

Checking [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Script_handlers)

> **expiration**
>
> Optional. The length of time a static file served by this handler
>   ought to be cached by web proxies and browsers. **The value is a string**
>   **of numbers and units**, separated by spaces, where units can be `d` for
>   days, `h` for hours, `m` for minutes, and `s` for seconds. For
>   example, `"4d 5h"` sets cache expiration to 4 days and 5 hours after
>   the file is first requested. See Static cache expiration. If omitted,
>   the application's default_expiration is used.

---

Inspecting your files

At several points in *ferris/include.yaml* you have blocks like this that use `expiration`

```
- url: /ferris/fonts
  static_dir: ferris/static/fonts
  expiration: 7d
```

After having read the docs we know it expects a string (which is a scalar type) and you are giving it `7d` which it supposedly recognizes as a *sequence start* as mentioned in the error.

---

Solution

The solution should be as simple as changing all values for `expiration` to be strings, for example

```
- url: /ferris/fonts
  static_dir: ferris/static/fonts
  expiration: "7d"
```

Note the inserted double quotes.